# Generate list of pattern contained in dictionary values Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have the following dictionary as an input of a Python script:

```
d = {
'A':[[1,2,7]], 
'B':[[1,3,7], [1,3], [1,7]],
'C':[[1,3,7], [2,6]],
'D':[[1,3,2], [2,1,3]]
}
```

and I want the following patterns as outputs:

```
{
(2,7):['A'],
(3,7):['C'],
(2,6):['C'],
(2,3):['D'],
(1,2):['A','D'],
(1,7):['A','B','C'],
(1,3):['B','C','D']
}
```

in which the resulting values should be generated considering the existence of a pair of indices in the values of the dictionary d.

For instance the pair (1,3) exists in the sublists of the values 'B', 'C', and 'D'

```
'B':[[1,3,X]],
'C':[[1,3,X]],
'D':[[1,3,X], [X,1,3]]
```

and the pair (2,7) exists only in the sublist of the key 'A'

Comment: For `(3,7)`, you would also need to add `B`. Also, if there could be duplicate pairs for the same key, I would suggest to clean this first as it would save the effort put into generating a lot of duplicate combinations for no good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
from itertools import combinations

d = {
    "A": [[1, 2, 7]],
    "B": [[1, 3, 7], [1, 3], [1, 7]],
    "C": [[1, 3, 7], [2, 6]],
    "D": [[1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]],
}

out = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    for subl in v:
        for c in combinations(subl, 2):
            out.setdefault(tuple(sorted(c)), set()).add(k)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    (1, 2): {"D", "A"},
    (1, 7): {"B", "C", "A"},
    (2, 7): {"A"},
    (1, 3): {"B", "D", "C"},
    (3, 7): {"B", "C"},
    (2, 6): {"C"},
    (2, 3): {"D"},
}
```

Comment: I upvoted but using `set()` as the second argument of `setdefault` makes me cringe a bit because this means that `set()` will always be called, even if there already exists an entry for `tuple(sorted(c))`.

Comment: Doesn't match the wanted output for `(3,7)`.

Comment: With `sorted(subl)` you wouldn't need to sort later.

Comment: @KellyBundy `B` does exist for `(3,7)`. Isn't it?

Comment: @nice_dev I think so, yes, but the OP left it out. I'd request clarification/fixing before posting an answer.

Comment: @Stef seconded. `defaultdict(set)` would be a better option.

Comment: One of the problem Is the complexity of the operation when the size of the sets increases. Is there any data structures that can make efficient this extraction?

Comment: @Stefano The number of things that can potentially be extracted matches the complexity of the extraction operation. That fact will limit any possible optimization. But going the other way, this can be written as a map-reduce. And so it is not too hard to distribute the computation at scale.

Comment: @btilly The "naive" extraction might do duplicate work. Just take the question's `'D':[[1,3,2], [2,1,3]]` for example. After extracting from `[1,3,2]`, extracting from `[2,1,3]` won't yield anything further, so that could be skipped.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes. You can put out work to potentially eliminate duplicate work. This does not improve your worst case. But it does not hurt it much either. Whether it improves your average case depends on the distribution of data that you actually have.

Answer (score 1):

Using combinations from itertools , you can create a set of pairs in ascending order and combine them in a list for each key (starting for a set of sorted pairs ensures that you only map keys once per pair):

```
d = {
'A':[[1,2,7]], 
'B':[[1,3,7], [1,3], [1,7]],
'C':[[1,3,7], [2,6]],
'D':[[1,3,2], [2,1,3]]
}

from itertools import combinations
    
r = dict()
for k,ls in d.items():
    for p in set().union(*(combinations(sorted(s),2) for s in ls)):
        r.setdefault(p,[]).append(k)

print(r)
               
{(1, 7): ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
 (1, 2): ['A', 'D'], 
 (2, 7): ['A'], 
 (3, 7): ['B', 'C'], 
 (1, 3): ['B', 'C', 'D'], 
 (2, 6): ['C'], 
 (2, 3): ['D']}
```

*Note that your sample result is missing 'B' in the (3,7) pair (or a rule to explain its absence).*

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code, Maybe it's simple way but it's correct

```
from itertools import combinations
d = {
  "A": [[1, 2, 7]],
  "B": [[1, 3, 7], [1, 3], [1, 7]],
  "C": [[1, 3, 7], [2, 6]],
  "D": [[1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]],
}

combination_output = {}

for letters,dicts  in d.items():
  for i in dicts:
    for comb in combinations(i,2):
      combination_output.setdefault(tuple(sorted(comb)), set()).add(letters)

print('{')
for z in combination_output:
  
  print(f"{z} : {combination_output[z]}")
print('}')
```